# Undoing/retracting vote to reopen question that was closed as duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, closed-questions, votes

I voted to reopen [Finding address with coordinates?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309129/) before realizing that it is in fact a duplicate of the question it's currently marked as a duplicate of.

Can I retract my reopen vote?

Comment: cleared - please check I got the right dup link.. thanks

Comment: @Mapperz Thanks, that is a better duplicate than the previous one. So is the answer to my question "no, only a moderator can do that" ?

Comment: you should have the rep 10k for Moderator tools https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges > https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability to retract re-open votes is the subject of a feature request at Meta Stack Exchange - see [Ability to retract reopen/delete votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193061/ability-to-retract-reopen-delete-votes).

It has been open for more than 5 years and appears not to have been implemented nor declined by the Stack Exchange developers.